# jenkins kubernetes plugin set workspaceVolume does not work

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins

I am following the doc:https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin , and set a hostPathWorkspaceVolume as the workspaceVolume int podTemplate, but it got an error when start the pod, below is my podTemplate yaml:

```
podTemplate(
    workspaceVolume: hostPathWorkspaceVolume(hostPath: "/opt/workspace"),
    yaml: '''
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: base-container
    image: python:2.7
    command: ['sleep', '99d']
    volumeMounts:
    - name: dockersock
      mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
    - name: dockerbin
      mountPath: /usr/bin/docker
  volumes:
  - name: dockersock
    hostPath:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
  - name: dockerbin
    hostPath:
      path: /usr/bin/docker
''')
```

and the error is:

```
23:10:52  jenkins-demo-253-pwlzb-qt66s-678gm Container jnlp was terminated (Exit Code: 1, Reason: Error)
23:10:52  [Pipeline] // node
23:10:52  [Pipeline] }
23:10:52  [Pipeline] // podTemplate
23:10:52  [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
23:10:52  ERROR: Queue task was cancelled
23:10:52  Finished: FAILURE
```

The host node has the dir "/opt/workspace".

I want to use Docker-on-Docker mode, so I want to change the default jenkins workspace.

Anyone can help to fix the hostPathWorkspaceVolume problem ? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the permission for your `HostWorkspacePath` folder *(/opt/workspace)*. Does Jenkins have permission to write in this directory.

I was also was facing with the same issue and after changing the directory permission, It works for me.